# How to get past messages from a specific channel in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Basically I want to have my bot get me messages from a specific channel.

Example:

```
#general contains:
Hello
Hi
Welcome
```

The bot should be able to output once commanded to something like
Hello, Hi, Welcome

I tried ctx.history, but that went horribly wrong and it gave me a long list of everything but the messages.

Comment: Please show code. No one can help debug if we don't know what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

Since `ctx` has attributes corresponding to many, many different objects, `ctx.history()` probably called the 'wrong' `history()` method, returning an `AsyncIterator` for the messages in a different channel. (See this [documentation search](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search.html?q=history) for a list of the many `history()` methods which could have been called.)

So, the solution would be to specify that you want the `TextChannel` history:

```py
async for message in ctx.channel.history():
    ...
```

Or, if the desired channel is *not* where the command was called:

```py
channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.channels, id=CHANNEL_ID)
async for message in channel.history():
    ...
```

Comment: You can also `msgs = await channel.history().flatten()` in case you don't want to use an `async for`

Comment: ctx.history() will always reference ctx.channel.history(). Additionally, ctx.channel can be a DMChannel too.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a brief command that grabs the history of a given channel and outputs it to a .txt file:

```py
@bot.command
async def log_channel(self, ctx):
  filename = str(ctx.channel.name)
    with open(f"{filename}.txt", "w+") as fp:
      async for msg in ctx.channel.history(limit=None):
        try:
          towrite = f"[{msg.author.name}] @ [{msg.created_at}] said: {msg.clean_content} \n"
        except:
          towrite = "message unreadable. likely an image?"
        fp.write(towrite)
  await ctx.send(file=discord.File(f"{filename}.txt"))
```

What you likely did wrong with calling `ctx.history` was that you were expecting it to return a list of messages in text form - it doesn't do that, it returns the message *objects*. You can read more about `discord.Message` [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message). There are two ways to get the text from a message object, you can either call `discord.Message.content`, or you can call `discord.Message.clean_content`. Personally, I find `clean_content` to be much more useful for applications such as logging, where the messages are not necessarily going to be saved in discord where the mentions can render appropriately. `clean_content` strips all mentions and replaces them with a text version of themselves, so for example [<#id> turns into #name.](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message.clean_content) [`discord.Message.content`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message.content) on the other hand returns everything in a form where <#id> remains <#id>. It does not turn into #name. Choose which one you find more appropriate for what you are doing, and run with it.